# Angular 2 - Dynamic component template - how to clone a FormControl on demand

Tags: angular, clone, angular-reactive-forms

I implemented a dynamic data table, so far so good,

at the bottom of the table, there is a row containing inputs for some columns that allow the user to add a new record, and each added row is editable

my issue is that when I inline edit a row, I need the same validation, so I need to clone the FormControl I defined for the bottom row

here is an example of a definition I use in my code, when I instanciate my data table component (for one column)

```
...,
{
  name: this.getTrad('Points'),
  value: 'points',
  width: 100,
  type: DataTableComponent.INPUT,
  editable:true,
  numeric:true,
  validationControl:
    new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false },
      [Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(1), 
      Validators.maxLength(100)
    ])
},
```

so, how could I clone the FormControl to assign it to a dynamicaly created input ?
I checked a FormControl instance, there is no accessor for the validators ?

so far the only idea I have is to give to my component an array of validators for each column instead of a whole instance of FormControl

if anyone has a better idea....

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this question. I solved the following use case with a normal new instance:

```
@Component({...})
export class FooDialogComponent {
  formControl: FormControl;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { system: number, control: AbstractControl }, // TODO define interface
             public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UpdateQuantityDialogComponent>) 
  {
    this.formControl = new FormControl(this.data.control.value, this.data.control.validator);
  }
}
```

With this approach, `formControl` has the same `state` and `validators` than the injected `AbstractControl`.

Ofc, in case that the `value` of the control isnt a primitive type, youll need to perform a (deep)copy.

Hope it helps

Comment: nice, I'll give it a try for sure

Comment: any news? @phil1234

Comment: yes sorry I finaly changed the way I create my validators, I retain the structure informationin another array, If I remember well I tried your code but had undefined values...but thanks anyway